# Fetch facebook post in Angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api

I am new to angularjs. I would like to fetch my facebook post in Angularjs application.

Kindly advice me how to start up this process through Angularjs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Please start exploring all Facebook API's for authorizing in different domain.Below is the Facebook API document which might help you to understand on how to get authorized to use FB API's
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/angularjs - it will create a setup like plugins inside your app after you include it in your angularjs app.

- For AngularJs app please create a angular scaffolding templates using Yoeman
  generator for project setup - cmd - 'yo angular' will help you to
  create angularjs application.
- To run your application locally / to create proxies/ to build and zip use -
  GruntJS
- To check your dependencies for your project use bower/npm
- Basically you need angular, angular-route, angular-resources as your
  dependency to your application.
- Start exploring about angular route,angular module,controllers,services,directives in angularjs website.

Comment: Do you need more help? or is this answer useful for you?

Comment: thanks again, I just go through above mentioned documents. Will ask if I need anything.